# SQL Server 2005 - clicking on job->Properties yields "New Job" window

Tags: sql-server-2005

Recently, I've started having a problem with my SQL Server 2005 client running on Windows XP where right-clicking on any job and selecting Properties instead brings me to the New Job window.  Also, if I select "View History", I get the history for all jobs, instead of the one I right-clicked on.

This happened to me once before, and I found that I hadn't installed a service pack for SQL 2005.  Once I installed it, the problem went away, and I haven't seen it in about a year.  I haven't run any updates on it since, and I'm not sure what could have caused this.

As a possibly related note, I've tried installing XP Service Pack 3 on my machine twice, and it just hung on my machine(I started running it on Friday before leaving for the weekend, and it hadn't gone more than5-10% when I got back on Monday).  I'm not sure if that fact is related at all, but I thought it possible that the XP update somehow overwrote something that SQL 2005 used before hanging.

Any ideas on what could cause this?  I've included the current version info that shows up in SQL 2005.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 9.00.1399.00
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools - 2005.090.1399.00
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) - 2000.085.1117.00 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)
Microsoft MSXML - 2.6 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
Microsoft Internet Explorer - 7.0.5730.13
Microsoft .NET Framework - 2.0.50727.1433
Operating System - 5.1.2600

Update:  I reinstalled SQL 2005 service pack 2 on my machine and it fixed the problem.  I'll have to see if the problem was caused when I tried installing xp sp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following path:

1. Make sure that you have current backups for the server
2. Try to get a clean install of the XP service pack
3. Try reinstalling the client tools on the machine
4. If that fails, try to install (or reinstall) SP2 for SQL Server